# Return, inside or outside Try / catch?

Tags: php, try-catch

In the below code, the IDE alerts me about "Missing return statement" in the last bracket. Which leads me to ask here if the return inside the `try{}` is ok or should be outside it.

Thanks a lot.

```
public function getFileNamesFromKeywords( array $ids, $format ) {
    try {
      if(self::$dbLink) {
        $ids = implode(',',$ids);
        $query = 'SELECT d.id, d.wfid, d.docid , k.keyword, k.value'.
          'FROM keywords k'.
          'INNER JOIN documents d '.
          'ON k.document_id = d.id'.
          'WHERE k.document_id IN ('.$ids.')';
        $results = self::$dbLink->query($query);

        if( $results === false ) {
          throw new Exception('Ocurrió un error al consultar a la DB.', 500);
        }
        $results = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $filenames = $this->buildFileNames( $results, $ids, $format );
      }
      else {
        throw new Exception('No hay una conexión establecida con la DB.', 500);
      }
      return $filenames;
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
      $this->error = 'Error al intentar conectar con la BD: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
  } //<----- Missing return statement
```

Comment: Either after the catch or inside a finally clause

Comment: ide are stupid :) Not all methods must return something.

Comment: @skler no but then they should be set to return `void`. Then the IDE will not moan. Otherwise if you state some return type, the IDE is warning you that you are not returning it. It's good advice 99% of the time, in PHPStorm at least

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If an exception is thrown and caught, what will the function return?

You should have a return statement in the catch block, or after the try-catch block. Having a return statement in the try-block only is not enough.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I put the return in the catch block and the alert disappeared.

Answer (score 19):

if you place a return statement inside a function at any location then it's expected that the function has to return something and since you have placed the return statement inside a try-catch block ,when the IDE evaluates thw code it notices that you don't have a return statement for when your try fails that is in the catch.

I would recommended creating a $response variable initialized to false at the top of the function then assign the $filenames to it then after the try-catch block return the $response.

```
function getFilenames(){
    $response = false;

    try{
        //your code
        $response = $filenames;
    }catch{

    }

    return $response;
}
```

By doing so you ensure that the function always returns something either the results you need or false.

Comment: I disagree. If code is short and clean as it should be, seeing a return inside a try catch with the return (eg) being another class call or whatever, I expect the code the return is using to potentially throw an exception. Saves setting a variable for nothing

Answer (score 2):

The message you are being given is just a warning, as your code may not return anything. The best option to do as add a return to your catch if you want to stop the warning.

Just add the return before the closing brace.

```
catch(Exception $e) {
    $this->error = 'Error al intentar conectar con la BD: ' . $e->getMessage();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `return null;` is same as `return;`, but it is shorter ;)

Comment: It's good practise to do `return null` as it clearly displays that you are returning a null value.

Comment: @GarethLuckett I never realized that PHP had so much in common with [existentialist philosophy](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/1h1cyg/whats_the_most_intellectual_joke_you_know/).

Comment: @GarethLuckett: `return;` also clearly displays that you are returning null. If I wanted to clearly display all coding in PHP, then all code should look like `json_decode($var, FALSE, 512, 0);` instead of `json_decode($var);`...

Comment: Its what I have been taught, I didn't realise that it would be a big issue.

Comment: Well I agree with Gareth, because someone can think that return alone could be "false" and avaluate against it with type included. Since this is just 4 letters, I do not see it being a big deal and adds to the readability of the code.

Comment: 8 years later, just to add: `return null` is not the same as `return`, as `return` means that a function is returning void, not null.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that generaly speaking proper place for return statement is inside of finally part

```
function doSomenthing() {
    $result = SomeDefaultValue;
    try {
        // code
        $result = ResultValueIfEverythingIsOK;
    }
    catch {
        // error handler code
    }
    finally {
        return ($result);
    }
}
```

You can get unhandled exception inside your error handler code and then you don't have guarantee that return statement will be executed unless it is inside finally part.