# How should I fix this code smell in my try/catch block

Tags: php, try-catch

OK. I get a code smell warning in my IDE. I understand why, and understand that the warning isn't especially dire. However, if there is a better way to write this block, I would like to know.

```
public function factory($state_name = 'Generic')
{
    ...

    try {
        if (!$class_exists) {
            throw new CustomException;
        } else {
            return new $class_name;
        }
    }
    catch (CustomException $c) {
        echo ...
    }

}
```

I don't return a value outside of the `try` block. Smell goes away if I return one at the end. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is your understanding of the "why"?

Comment: what warning did you get?

Comment: @M.AdamKendall I don't return anything outside of the `try/catch` block. When I put a return statement there, it goes away.

Comment: @TheGuest "Missing return statement" is the description my IDE returns to me.

Comment: @nobrandheroes See this post for your understanding : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963053/return-inside-or-outside-try-catch

Comment: @TheGuest The post gives me 3 options: 1. Use a finally block. 2. Return null. 3. Set a response variable. The response variable, as someone called it is what I was doing, but it seems unnecessary for many cases. Should I just return null?

Comment: @nobrandheroes I guess return null; in catch block is fine for your code

Comment: @TheGuest if you want to convert this to an answer, I'll mark my post as answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75138/discussion-between-the-guest-and-nobrandheroes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bigger code smell for me is that you are throwing an exception and then immediately catching it. It seems that you are doing this to avoid returning anything, which of course, your IDE is complaining about. 
I would rewrite this as:

```
public function factory($state_name = 'Generic')
{
    ...

    if ($class_exists) {
        return new $class_name;
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: Not avoiding returning anything, just wanting custom error messages, and at some point custom logging.

Comment: In which case, you can log right before returning null.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is a factory and should implicitly return something it created.  In statically typed languages such as Java you have to declare a return type, and would have to return something regardless.  Your function written in a statically typed language wouldn't compile.  We don't have these problems with PHP so you are able to do this, but it is smelly for sure.  It's good practice to have your function behave in a consistent manor i.e. always returning something regardless of what happened.  I would return null after your try/catch and always check the value returned from this function wherever it's used.